# How can I detect parameter types of a function passed as a parameter?

Tags: c++, function, templates, lambda, variadic-templates

### Problem

I have to write a function that will be used as:

```
obj.transform([](x& a, y& b) { ... });
obj.transform([](x& a) { ... });
obj.transform([](y const& a, x& b, z const& c) { ... });
obj.transform([a, b](z const& c) { ... });
...
```

and inside the function declaration, I need to figure out the type of the arguments passed in.

The body of the function is then in the form (assuming `x` to be a member object and `argfn` the function passed in):

```
if (x.mfn1<std::remove_reference_t<Args>...>())
    argfn(x.mfn2<std::remove_reference_t<Args>>()...);
```

### Context

If you are asking yourself, why and you have no idea how this could be useful, or if you think this is an XY problem, then you can find [the context right here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aed00a1ffec910f7).

### My attempts

**Attempt #1**

```
template<typename... Args>
void fn(std::function<void(Args...)>) { ... }
```

This [doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a3dbf474139e5ae) because there's apparently no way to have a conversion between that `std::function` and any lambda.

**Attempt #2**

```
template<typename... Args>
void fn(void(*)(Args...)) { ... }
```

This works with the first, second and third example above (prepending `+` on each lambda to force a conversion to pointer to function), but [fails on the fourth](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/934546dfd532d33c).

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/traits.hpp

Comment: So, you pass in callables, deduce the types needed to call it, check if you have those types, and then invoke.  That implies that you can only ever have one object of a given type in your entity, which seems like a strange restriction.  Two small changes to [your linked code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ee2d6aefacb01cf) make it compile.

Comment: You need the argument types? If the lambda isn't generic, just look at its `operator()`.

Comment: To be insane, the dual of an entity is of type `any(any) -> (any|typeerror)` (to mix haskell and C++ function notation horribly).  Curry incoming functions, feed to duals of entities, done?  Naw, doesn't work, as mapping `auto(auto)` to `any(any)` isn't feasible, and finding what entity dual to call requires linear search of the entities.  Both can be fixed, but basically involve manual or automatic signature deduction, which make it silly.

Comment: @Yakk "That implies that you can only ever have one object of a given type in your entity, which seems like a strange restriction." What do you mean? With that given code, every `entity` can contain any number of other object types.

Comment: @Yakk Your linked example, unfortunately, does not satisfy any of the requirements described in the question. For example, simply removing explicit types from `transform` in main, results in [our well known compile error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e5c8d6dc5cdb735).

Comment: The objects "in" the entity I sm talking about are ... the components? ... the arguments you want to look up based on the call signature of the invokable object you are passing in.  Thd implicit restriction in your code is that they are of distinct type.  Which seems to me to be a strange restriction.  Tagging them makes sense (so we can name them), but tagging them with their type seems strange in C++.

Comment: @Yakk Oh I see your point, but no. In this context it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Jefffrey So did you extract the "get argument types" from the above link?  If you require that (A) the set of types you support is not limited, and (B) the code that adds the component to the entity has no common dependencies (other than entity) with (C) the code that calls the function, and (D) you are ok with C++14 style lambdas not working, and (E) you have that strange feature where the type determines the value, then that approach is probably the best.  I can probably find a SO dupe for it if you'd like.

Comment: @Yakk Sorry, "that approach is probably the best". What's "that"?

Comment: @Jefffrey The answer to my first question in the post in question.

Comment: @Yakk Do you consider comments as posts? And what is the first question? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864681/how-can-i-detect-parameter-types-of-a-function-passed-as-a-parameter?noredirect=1#comment47856307_29864681) there's no question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864681/how-can-i-detect-parameter-types-of-a-function-passed-as-a-parameter?noredirect=1#comment47856990_29864681) neither. Also is the "post in question" this very question?

Comment: @jeff Ok, so I made a comment (which is a kind of post).  In it I asked a question, and went on with more details.  You asked what "that" meant in the context of a comment I made.  I said "that" refers to the question's (the thing that ended with a ? in the comment you where referring to) answer (the link, in Dieter's comment above).  Did you extract the code that gives you lambda argument types from Dieter's link, and did it solve your problem?  If that does solve your problem, I can find another post on SO with substantially identical content to Dieter's link, and close this question down.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not sure about Dieter's link. I'm trying to read that code and it appears to me like I would have to use `blabla::arg<0>, blabla::arg<1>, ...`, and applying that to my problem would have to use a syntax I'm not familiar with. When I'll have some time I'll give it a deeper try. What would the duplicate be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. For example, what if the argument is a functor containing a templated (especially variadic) `operator()`? Or one that is overloaded? What are the "arguments" then?

The core problem here is that you're effectively re-implementing ranges but worse. Just offer plain iterators over the entities and then use `std::transform`. Or find a range library of your choice.

Comment: "what if the argument is a functor containing a templated (especially variadic) operator()", I'm fine with that failing with a compile error in the forms of "cannot deduce type ...".